# how to check USB storage on Linux

Tags: linux, usb

After I mount a USB storage on Linux, how do I know at what 'mode' this USB device is working at? Such as USB 1.0 or 2.0, full speed, high speed, etc. I need to know what the 'expected' speed is.

Thanks.

Comment: hdparm reads ATA parameters. It won't work on most USB storage devices, and won't return the USB mode anyways.

Comment: as duskwuff said, hdparm doesn't seem to fit my need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lsusb -v, find your USB stroage in result and there will be for example:

```
bcdUSB 2.00
```

it means that this device is USB 2.0 (hi-speed) device.

But it doesn't mean that this device will always work as hi-speed device. Sometimes in some case of errors this device can work as full-speed.

If you see such a message in dmesg like this:

```
usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
```

it means that it will be working as hi-speed device. If linux kernel will have any problems with hi-speed communication it may switch to full-speed and it will write appropriate message in dmesg.

Just take a look at dmesg result after you connect your usb storage.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes I saw 'bcdUSB 2.00' using 'lsusb -v', and saw the followings in dmesg:
[260239.707853] usb 1-1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[260239.820730] usb 1-1.4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[260239.821234] scsi7 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[260239.821478] usb-storage: device found at 6
[260239.821482] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[260241.485914] usb-storage: device scan complete
So seems it's working in 2.0 high-speed mode.

Comment: more questions: but the speed doesn't seem correct. I was calculating the speed of writing to USB using this command: 'rm -rf /mnt/usb/*; sync; date; time { cp /path/to/a/file /mnt/usb/.; sync; }; date', and the speed is about 3M bytes/sec. (We know USB 2.0 high-speed is supposed to be 60M bytes/sec.) Anything wrong here? Or, is my calculation approach wrong? (I noticed that the 'sync' command after 'cp' takes quite a while to finish, but I do think 'sync' after 'cp' is necessary.) Any hints are welcome!

Comment: It seems that your device is working at hi-speed. 3MB/s is rather slow transmission speed, but I dont't know how old is your usb storage (older usb storage are slower). It is hard to say where is the problem of such slow speed.